# Error when not using the defined layer in call method in Keras model with WandB integration

Tags: tensorflow, keras, wandb

When defining a new Keras model and integrating it with WandB (Weights and Biases), I encountered an error related to a specific layer. The error message I received is as follows:

```bash
File "/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wandb/data_types.py", line 1504, in from_keras
    node = Node.from_keras(layers[i])
  File "/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wandb/data_types.py", line 1731, in from_keras
    node.num_parameters = layer.count_params()
ValueError: You tried to call `count_params` on layer conv1d, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: `conv1d.build(batch_input_shape)`.
```

Steps to Reproduce:

- Define a new Keras model.
- Include a specific layer within the `__init__` method of the model.
- Do not use the aforementioned layer in the `call` method of the model.
- Integrate the Keras model with WandB for tracking.

Expected Behavior:
The model should integrate with WandB without any errors, even if there are layers defined in the `__init__` method that is not used in the `call` method.

Actual Behavior:
The error mentioned above is raised when trying to integrate the Keras model with WandB.

Code Snippet:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import wandb

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
        # Other layers...

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Only using other layers, not `conv1d`
        return inputs

# WandB initialization
wandb.init(project="my-project", mode='disabled')
config = wandb.config

# Create and integrate the model
model = MyModel()

wandb_callback = wandb.keras.WandbCallback(
    monitor="val_loss", 
    verbose=0, 
    mode="min", 
    save_model=False
)

x_train, y_train = tf.random.uniform([100, 10]), tf.random.uniform([100, 10])
wandb.config.update(config)  # Update config with any hyperparameters
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, callbacks=[wandb_callback])
wandb.log({"example_metric": 0.85})
wandb.finish()
```

Please let me know if you need any further information or clarification.

#### Environment

WandB version: 0.15.8

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Python version: 3.9.16

TensorFlow Version: [2.12.0]

Comment: Thanks for writing Salman. This is not a W&B keras callback issue. If you initialise the model and call `model.summary()` you will get the error. The custom model's call method is used to build the model and layer defined in the `__init__` has to be called. The model is first converted to graph and the call method is responsible for passing the tensor shapes to the layers.

Comment: Hi Ayush, actually if you try running the code I've written above, you will get the error I'm getting.
while by removing the wandb_call back I am not getting the error. I do not call the `model.summary()` anywhere.  
just please try running the code above.

Comment: People are pointing that IF you use model.summary(), you get the same error, providing it is not a problem with wandb.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy This is exactly the problem with wandb.  now if `model.summary()` raises the same problem, it is something else. 
here w&b should capture the error and handle it. anyway I opened an issue in wandb GitHub repo, and they approved that it is a wandb issue: https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/6046

Comment: You keep misinterpreting what people say, in the wandb issue, they did not say that it is a wandb issue, they say they reproduced the error, which is not the same.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy if you run my code once with `wandb_callback ` and once without, you will see that calling `wandb_callback ` will lead to an error.
it does not have anything to do with `model.summary()` or anything else. 
Also, from the error log, it is clear that wandb causes the problem: `file "/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wandb/data_types.py"`
anyway, if they solve the issue, one can check it on: github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/6046

Comment: No, I can reproduce the error without using wandb, just define your model and call model.summary(). The problem is NOT in wandb but in your own code.

Comment: I'm not gonna waste my time arguing with you! have a nice day

Comment: No need to waste time, just look at my new answer. We can reproduce the error without using wandb. And the solution is pretty simple, just call build on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not specific to `wandb`, the problem is in the users' code since the model and inner layers does not have a specified input shape. To reproduce the error without wandb:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
        # Other layers...

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Only using other layers, not `conv1d`
        return inputs

# Create and integrate the model
model = MyModel()
    
model.conv1d.count_params()
```

This will output: `ValueError: You tried to call` count_params`on layer conv1d, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via:`conv1d.build(batch_input_shape)`.`

To fix it, just call build on your model with the shape of the input data minus the batch shape, for example here I use `(32, 32, 3)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
        # Other layers...

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Only using other layers, not `conv1d`
        return inputs

# Create and integrate the model
model = MyModel()

model.build((32,32,3))

model.summary()
```

The error is gone and you can use the model. In any case you have not built the inner layers, which you should also do if you plan on using them somehow, just by calling `build` on them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1d = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
        # Other layers...
        self.conv1d.build((32,32,3))

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Only using other layers, not `conv1d`
        return inputs

# Create and integrate the model
model = MyModel()

model.build((32,32,3))

print(model.conv1d.count_params())
```

This correctly prints 640 for the given input shape. In the end I reiterate, the problem is not in `wandb` but in your model as it has unused layers that do not have defined input shapes, just calling `build` on them will make everything work.

Comment: No, even if you build the model, you still have a problem when you use the wandb_callback. 
you can bypass the problem if you build the layer you've defined in `__init__ `or by callding the defined layer in `call`, i.e. `self.conv()` without passing the output to anywhere else.
but this is not a right solution

Comment: @Salman You still have what problem? And you seem to imply that this is a solution, but not a "right solution", whatever you mean by that.

Comment: even if you build the model, as a way you said, when you use `wandb_callback`, you will face the same error

Comment: The problem is when you are using, wandb, this package use `node.num_parameters = layer.count_params()` method that this method raises an error.

the use should not be responsible for the misbehavior of a certain package, 
wandb should handle the error, and should not leave it for a user to figure out what to do. 
this is a simple code that I've written here, my original code is much bigger and it is not possible to build the layer each time within __init__, as I do not know the exact shape of the input.

Comment: I have now reproduced the error with count_params() and fixed it by giving the layer a defined input shape. You should really listen, wandb expects a properly made Keras model, which you are not making. You should simply not use the model until it is properly built with a input shape, you can delay initialization of wandb until that point.

Comment: your second sentence makes sense but my model is much bigger and more complex than I mentioned here.
As I mentioned, I do not know the exact shape of the input when I'm building the model.

Comment: That is actually a different problem, note that in Stack Overflow we solve the problem presented in the question, not the other problem you might have and not have disclosed. And you can also build a model multiple times.

Comment: @Salman It is very dissapointing that we put time to write an answer to your question and you just dismiss it because you have a hidden problem that we are not aware of, as I said, we answer the problem in the question, not the problem you might derive from it. If the answer solves the problem in the question, you should accept and possible upvote.